# Locate an ASCII art image inside a body of text with a certain toleration for error

Tags: java, algorithm, search, ascii-art

Are there any algorithms that would find the following ASCII-art image?

```
    +
    +
   +++
 +++++++
 ++   ++
++  +  ++
++ +++ ++
++  +  ++
 ++   ++
 +++++++
   +++
```

Inside the following body of text?

[complete_file_here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/28167627/TestData.txt)

```
              + +    +              ++           +       +++    +     +
 +  ++     +   + ++++    + +       +         +          +  +   +++     +++ +
     +            + +   ++      ++  ++    + ++       +     +      +  +   +
+   ++      +  ++       +          + +       ++        ++  +           +
 ++++++ + +    +   ++  +  +   +   +  ++      +         +                     +
  + +   +      +               +      ++     +  ++            +   +    + +
+++   + ++   +  +            +  +++       + +       ++                     +
  +++++  +      +                            +  + +            +   +  +
 +   +   +              +    +      +            +  +   +      +    +     +
 ++    +              +     +       ++   +          +       +           ++
```

I must highlight the ASCII art image in yellow which corresponds to the complete shape. See the picture attached:

[image]

I have to search a file which contains the rough shape, but not completely, a number of `+` can be missing). The tolerance for a missing `+` in the shape should be set by hand.

Now, I have two 2D arrays data array: [100][100] and the SlimeTorpedo array: [13][11].

Code for how to make the detection as stated by @kjartan (3-4 bullet):

```java
int match = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
        //Compare DataArr[i][j] with SlimeTorpedoArr[i][j]
        //Look for "checked" position in the picture ("+"), 
        //which corresponds to a checked position in the 
        //slime torpedo array.
        //match++;
    }
}
```

What would be general guidance for how to approach this problem?

Comment: Can you provide more context on that algorithm please?

Comment: What level of inaccuracy is acceptable?  Your question is very ill defined.

Comment: The level of inaccuracy has no importance, I must detect the shape and say for instance : "It miss 5 or 6 "+" on shape detected "

Comment: That's exactly what is meant by the level of inaccuracy. How many missing/extra plus signs mean it's no longer the same shape?

Comment: Shape is always the same. But the shape contained in the data file is not exact. (Some "+" can miss but it's the same shape).
I started to create 2 Java arrays : one for the data, and another one for the shape.

Comment: I assume you are unconcerned with scale of the slime torpedo or the rotation of the slime torpedo?

Comment: It is the slime torpedo to detect.

Comment: Presumably the algorithm should check that at least one character boundary around the shape is empty of symbols (with the proviso that a few can be incorrect, as per the general fuzzy approach)?

Comment: @magister the complete file link is no more accessible and your provided test data chunk is just 10 lines in height while torpedo is 11 lines ...

Answer (score 4):

Let's say width and height parameters (in terms of number of characters) are known for your first shape. Let them be `width` and `height`.

- Encode your input into a 2D array of bits (or + signs). So you have
  `int[][] inputBits = new int[height][width];` and you should populate
  it correctly. (It's your task, dude.)
- Then apply a simple search on the larger shape (assuming it is
  encoded into another 2D array as well). Shift the pivot area to right
  by one each time (the pivot area is equivalent to the area of first
  shape) and check whether pivot area (2D array) has all its elements
  equal to the first shape. That's a brute-force algorithm =)

Comment: Would only find exact matches, needs some tweaking for incomplete matching but without specs on what constitutes a match I'd say this question is unanswerable.

Comment: @bdares the efficiency of my algorithm is questionable, anyway it will find the exact matches and I think OP wants to detect exact matches.

Comment: A match is when the algorithm detect a shape but not the exact shape (inaccuracy : missing some "+" character)

Comment: You can make it a "fuzzy" match fairly easily. In every step, instead of checking whether the pivot area has all equal elements, check that it has at least `A` equal elements and no more than `B` unequal elements. Then return the pivot area that has the fewest mismatches.

Answer (score 4):

Try brute-force with a match-score:

- Define a "square" around your "slime torpedo"; that is a 2D array with width and height a little wider and higher than your torpedo.
- In that 2D array, mark cells as either checked or unchecked, as necessary to create the image you want.
- Now loop through each character (let's call this an "index" position) in your full image, and for each, compare the positions near it with that of the corresponding character in the 2D array.
- Look for "checked" (or unchecked) position in the picture, which corresponds to a checked (or unchecked) position in the slime torpedo array (for instance, a char X above and Y left of the current index position in the picture, that matches the status X above and Y left of the center point of the slime torpedo array). For each such "match", add one "point" to that index position in the picture.

**Now here's the trick**: To make this a lot more effective, only check some of the positions in the slime-torpedo - for instance, every 10'th position or even less. That should reduce the running time by a factor of 10, roughly speaking.

That would mean you would have to check `(1/10)` * `the number of characters in the 2D array` for each character in the whole picture.

Now **keep track of the highest scoring positions** in the full picture. The highest scoring position should be the best match.

If you want, you could run this multiple times, with a varying degree of detail, for instance checking only 1/20 of the positions the first time, then 1/2, next, but this time focusing only on for instance the highest 20 (or 50? 100?) scoring positions from the first round.

(Alternatively, you could do a more detailed scan of all positions scoring higher than some threshold S).

Hope you'll let us know how it goes whatever you decide, interesting question! :)

***Update in response to the comments below:***

Maybe my explanation was a little unclear. In short / pseudo-code, you would need to do something like this to find the score for each cell:

```
foreach(DataArraRow dataRow in dataArray){
    foreach(IndexCell index in dataRow){        

        // initialy, no score for this cell in the data array:
        indexCell.score = 0;

        // Now iterate through all SlimeTorpedo cells, and compare the 
        // symbol in it to the corresponding symbol in te data array:
        foreach(SlimeArrayRow slimeRow in slimeTorpedoArray){
            foreach(SlimeTorpedoCell slimeCell in slimeRow){
                if(IsMatchingSymbol(slimeCell.xPosition, 
                                    slimeCell.yPosition, 
                                    slimeCell.symbol, 
                                    indexCell){
                    indexCell.score += 1;
                }else{
                    indexCell.score -= 1;
                }
            }              
        }

    }
}


Function IsMatchingSymbol(x, y, slimeSymbol, indexCell){
   // Find the cell in the data array corresponding to the 
   // "slimeCell" currently being checked:
   var cellToCheck = getCell(indexCell.xPosition + x, 
                             indexCell.yPosition + y);

   if(cellToCheck.symbol == slimeSymbol){
       return true;
   }else{
       return false;
   }

}
```

This is obviously a little messy, and I'm not sure about all the details, but I hope it shows a general idea which should work. When you're done iterating through this, iterate over all cells again, and pick up the highest scoring cells (or build a separate high-score list along the way - that would probably be quicker).

You will have to do a few changes, such as replacing the `ForEach` loops with a regular `For(int i=0; i < someArrayLength; i = i + levelOfDetail){ ... }` or something similar, where `levelOfDetail` is an integer with which you adjust the level of detail (i.e. how many cells in the SlimeTorpedoArray to check). I'm sure you can work it out... ;)

Comment: As per my comment under the question, I wonder whether the box around the shape need be square? It could be, depending on the OP's requirements, one character space around the outside of the shape.

Comment: @halfer: I don't see why it would have to be square, but it just seems easier to think of it as a square. Dosn't hurt to include a little more "whitespace" around the image anyway - that should only provide a more accurate algorithm, if I'm not mistaken (might take slightly longer though, as this would require slightly more comparisons).

Comment: I mention it only since the background of the highlighted "slime torpedo" appears to be very noisy. +1

Comment: Thank all of the contributors on this page. This where am I.
@kjartan to mark a cell it's easy : or it' marked with a "+" or it contain a white String "".
Now, I have two 2D arrays Data array : [100][100] and the SlimeTorpedo array: [13][11].

Sorry, but I don't get the 3rd and the 4th point ? I'm a beginner.
What I need to do to count the match : 
   for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
     //index = i.j
     //Look for "checked" position in the picture ("+"), which corresponds to a checked position in the slime torpedo array.
     //match++;
   } 
  }

Comment: @magister I updated my answer with some pseudo-code. Hope this helps make the idea a little clearer. I'm afraid you'll have to work out the nitty gritty details on your own though.. best of luck! ;)

Comment: @Kjartan, Thank you a lot, it's completely clear now. Now, let's code the idea. I'll make a link with the solution. I come back in a few days.

Answer (score 1):

For those interested, I solved this problem using XOR mapping in Java:

https://bitbucket.org/bluegod1/blifoscope-java/

It also takes into account that there might be false positives or duplicates, it has an option for specifying the minimum threshold for a good match, add a custom data image file, etc...